# implementing a state machine for servo motors

Tags: arduino, fsm

I have created a FSM for my servo. It has two states. I am using a switch/case structure but the motor is getting '**stuck**' in the first case and Im not sure why.

**This is my code:**

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define one 1
#define two 2


Servo myservo1; //projector platform servo

unsigned long Timer1; //define timer variable for state 1 if statement

void setup()
{
    myservo1.attach(9);
}

void loop(){

    static int state = one; // initial state is one.

    switch(state)
    {
    case one:
        myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1374); // servo is moving cw
        delay(5000);
        myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1474); // servo is stationary
        Timer1 = millis();
        if (millis() - Timer1 > 5000)
        {
            state = two;
        }
        break;

    case two:
        for(int speedv1 = 0; speedv1 <= 100; speedv1 += 2) // loop to ramp up speed of servos
        {
            myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1474 + speedv1); // speed increase by 2 each iteration (servo 1) until servo reaches fullspeed (ACW)
            delay(40); // delay between loop iterations
        }
        delay(5000);
        for(int speedv2 = 0; speedv2 <= 100; speedv2 += 2) // loop to ramp down servo speed
        {
            myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1574 - speedv2); // speed decrease by 2 each iteration (servo 1) until servo stops
            delay(40); //delay between loop iterations 
        }
        delay(2000);
        state = one;
        break;
    }
}
```

The motor seems to get stuck at

```
myservo1.writeMicroseconds(1374);
```

on the first line of `case 1`.

By stuck I mean the motor just continues to rotate in a clockwise fashion and does not progress to the next `writeMicroseconds()` statement after the delay. Appreciate the help.

Comment: I dont see how you expect millis() - Timer1 to ever be anything other than 0. As no time has passed between setting Timer1 and checking if 5 seconds have passed.

Answer (score 0):

With this piece of code in state one:

```
Timer1 = millis();
if (millis() - Timer1 > 5000)
{
    state = two;
}
```

it's *incredibly* unlikely that the timer will have advance five seconds between the first and second line. Hence because you change `Timer1` everyone time you run that bit of code, it will alway stay in state one.

Though it's unclear what exactly you're trying to achieve (I'm uncertain as to what the `writeMicroSeconds()` calls do, nor your need for the explicit delays within the states themselves), let's assume for now that you want to stay in state one for five seconds but do something else during that time. That means you need to initialise the start time as part of *moving* to state one, not within the state one code itself.

For example, the following code shows one way to do this, continuously running the servo clockwise for five seconds then anti-clockwise for four (with some mythical calls to start the servo running):

```
void loop() {
    static int state = zero;
    static unsigned long timer1;

    switch (state) {
        case zero: {
            timer1 = millis();
            state = one;
            servo.startClockwise();
            break;
        }
        case one: {
            if (millis() - timer1 >= 5000) {
                servo.stop();
                servo.startAntiClockwise();
                timer1 = millis();
                state = two;
            } else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
            break;
        }
        case two: {
            if (millis() - timer1 >= 4000) {
                servo.stop();
                servo.startClockwise();
                timer1 = millis();
                state = one;
            } else {
                doSomethingElse();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```